# Use Mongo $text search in limited set

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I'm having troubles finding a way to execute the following mongo text search:

I have a phrase: "I like apples" and I want to search if my messages collection already has this exact phrase in the content parameter of the collection but only in the last 5 entries. Is this possible to do? I tried something like this but I think it is applying the query to all the entries in the collection:

```
results = (
            self.message_collection..find(
            {"$text": {"$search": escaped_message}},
        )
            .sort("created_at", -1)
            .limit(5)
        )
```

Comment: The `.limit` option is used to set a limit for the maximum number of items returned. You can limit the number to search by using `.filter`, but that may not be applicable in your situation.

Comment: Hello @OldBoy! I don't know if that would work. from what I know ( that isn't much because I'm relatively new to mongo) the $text parameter must be the first one of a query and can't be applied to a find that's why I'm having trouble searching for a string content match but only on the last 5 messages of the collection. The text search is executing in all the collection I think

Comment: Yes, that is what I explained in my first message. If you want to search a subset of all items then you must use some form of filtering. For complete details se [find - MongoDB Manual](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/find/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.find).

Comment: ok sorry @OldBoy! Yes filter will be helpfull to limit the search to only a specific user messages but even so I think it will probably apply the text search to all that user messages not the last 5 messages he sent probably. may I will have to limit the search by search dates and apply the filter to the messages he sent on the last 2 mintues or something like that

Comment: _"... only in the last 5 entries"_  How do you identify the _"last 5 entries"_?  Does each document have a timestamp?

Comment: @rickhg12hs by the created_at parameter that i forgot to mention sorry. My idea was to sort by date and limit the return to 5 and then apply the text search to that filter but from what I studied I think that won't be possible

Comment: Isn't this [tutorial example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/sort-tutorial/#sort-dates) almost exactly what you are looking for?